# excel nested IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm having some trouble with the below formula:

```
=IF(Data!X:X = 1, 
IF(Data!H:H = "Horse", 
IF(Data!U:U = A5, COUNT(Data!U:U)),0)
```

I need to check if column "X" in the excel sheet "Data" as the value of "1" if so, I need to check another column (in the same sheet) to see if it contains a particular text element(like: horse"), then I have to check to see if the column U in sheet "Data" contains the same value as my active sheet A5 if all the criteria match I need the count of how many times this occurs.

however my formula is only returning FALSE. I narrow it down to this part;

```
"IF(Data!H:H = "Horse")
```

now I double check , all the IF should end up as true.

Obviously I have something not right, any help would be great.

Comment: `I need to check if column "X" in the excel sheet "Data" as the value of "1"`  - not sure what do you mean. You need to check whether column `X` _contains_ value `1`?

Comment: maybe something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((Data!X:X = 1)*(Data!H:H = "Horse")*(Data!U:U = A5))`?

Comment: That worked! SUMPRODUCT if you put this as a answer I will credit you the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later, you can use:

```
=COUNTIFs(Data!X:X, 1, Data!H:H, "Horse", Data!U:U , A5)
```

For Excel 2003:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!X:X = 1)*(Data!H:H = "Horse")*(Data!U:U = A5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the formula is incorrect (missing some of the `false` clauses in the `if` statements). This works for me:

```
=IF(Data!X:X = 1,
IF(Data!H:H = "Horse",
IF(Data!U:U = A5, COUNT(Data!U:U),0),0),0)
```

Comment: Thank Chris but I still have the same issue, it looks like SUMPRODUCT was the solution to my issue, thanks again!